# Using memcmp in C++ gives memory leak while running with Valgrind

Tags: c++, linux

I am using memcmp for comparing the char pointer to empty string as:

```
if((0 == memcmp("", pcNewBeginPtr, 1))){
    // do some stuff
}
```

I am able to compare this, but while running through Valgrind, I get this error message:

```
Invalid read of size 1 at this line.
```

Comment: And what is `pcNewBeginPtr`? What is it pointing at in the call?

Comment: Also, that's not a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly, you could read the docs to see what the "invalid read" message means.  E.g. you don't legitimately have read access to the memory at `pcNewBeginPtr`: it's already been freed, wasn't validly initialised to point at a `char` buffer, points to a local variable in a scope that's already exited etc....

You might read some other questions: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785710/valgrind-error-invalid-read-of-size-4).